# Input Signature converted to Brushed Signature

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, digital-signature

Is there any way to convert a signature into Brushed signature to any document by PHP/Javascript or jquery. If that so then please any one care to help me with that

Comment: What is a *brushed signature*? And what kind of signature do you want to convert into such a beast?

Comment: brushed signature is that kind of signature what we do in paper. I want that kind of signature digitally. What I knew a image generates with a pattern of the signature but I don't know how to create that.